# Сабинтерфейсы Сisco 800

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-ios

Настраиваю вланы, собрал стенд из живого маршрутизатора `C881-K9` с прошивкой `C800-UNIVERSALK9-M версии 15.6`. И свича `Edge Core ES3510MA` (прошивку не помню, да это и не важно). На свиче настроены 2 влана 10 и 11 и настроен один из портов как транковый. На маршрутизаторе так же добавил транковый порт `dot1q-tunnel` (на сколько я понимаю цисковский режим транка Edge Core скорее всего не поддерживает). А вот далее необходимо добавить сабинтерфейсы, в сети указано что они добавляются через `int fa 0/3.1` но в этой модели интерфейсы именуются просто как целое число `FastEthernet 3`. Но при попытке добавить такой вот командой `int fa 3.1` вылетает ошибка синтаксиса. ТО что сабинтерфейсы поддерживаются я уверен та как в подсказке есть пункт с точкой. Как правильно добавить подинтерфейс?
[Листинг](https://pastebin.com/TDQnUHJQ) циски.

Answer (score 0):

Все, сам разобрался. Нужно набирать как `int fa3.1` То биш 3 порт 1 сабинтерфейс.